# How to find three natural numbers $n_1, n_2, n_3$ with $n_1 < n_2 < n_3$ such that $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = 784$ and $n_1^2 + n_2^2 = n_3^2$

Tags: computational-mathematics

How to calculate the multiplying of the three numbers $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ where the summation of them equals 784 if you know the followings: $n_1, n_2, n_3$ are natural numbers $n_1 < n_2 < n_3$, $n_1^2 + n_2^2 = n_3^2$

Comment: You should probably change the title, since it's a mathematics QnA website it's obvious that there won't be any question about Doraemon.

Comment: In other words: find a Pythagorean triple $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ whose associated perimeter is $784$.

Answer (score 1):

For our purposes we can relax the constraint $n_1<n_2$ and assume $n_1=2dab,\,n_2=d(a^2-b^2),\,n_3=d(a^2+b^2)$ for naturals $a,\,b,\,d$ with $a>b,\,(a,\,b)=1$, so $da(a+b)=392=2^3 7^2$. We need $a+b<2a$ and $(a,\,a+b)=1$, so $a+b=2^3=8,\,a=7,\,b=1,\,d=7$ and $n_1 n_2 n_3 = 2\times 7^4\times (7^4-1^4)=11524800$.

Comment: If the question had $56$ instead of $784$, would you have got $d=\frac12$?

Comment: @Henry No: in that case $d=1,\,a=4,\,b=3$.

Comment: OK, though that might not satisfy your $a+b<2a$.  Relaxing that requirement could give $d=14, a=4, b=3$ as a solution in the $784$ case

Comment: @Henry Firstly, $4+3< 2\times 4$. Secondly, your proposed factorisation gives the same $n_1 n_2 n_3$, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: My mistake on the first point.  There is essentially one solution to the original question, but I had found it peculiar that a similar triangle was not giving the same $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Henry That's due to a subtlety in how Pythagorean triples work when you double or halve the numbers, viz. $a'=a+b,\,b'=a-b$ or the inverse transformation. This makes one parametrisation universal even though it seems at first as if parity concerns establish two.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $7,24,25$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple. Note that $7+24+25 = 56$ divides 784.

Comment: That leads to a solution, though it does not show whether there could be others